# How to add number to every .jpg book page?

Tags: jpg, jpeg

I have around 400 .jpg images of book pages, and they are not numbered.

They are already numbered in the filenames e.g. "8_9.jpg", "9_10.jpg" and so on.

I would like to automate adding page numbers to every .jpg, so every page looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to do with any program?

Comment: What is your end goal? I'm thinking the images need to be gathered in a PDF and not just end as separate JPGs in a folder? Which programs do you have access to? I would use Adobe InDesign. Setup a document in spreads, put page number on the master page, place all the images on separate pages, export PDF. It could perhaps also be coded using something like ImageMagick.

Comment: What have you tired? What software are you seeking to use? This can be done in probably hundreds of apps, as well as scripted for more core-script languages.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to do it would be by using Acrobat Pro. You can combine multiple image files into one pdf with `File > Create > Combine files... (or something)` then in `Tools > Organize pages` under the "more" menu you got `Bates numbering`. Doesn't get much simpler... — If I needed more control over it, I'd use Indesign and probably the [multipage importer script](https://creativepro.com/zanelli-releases-multipageimporter-for-importing-both-pdf-and-indd-files/) to get the pages in Indesign easily. But given that you had to ask the question, Indesign might be a tad too complex.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a small python script to make what you ask. You need to install python and install Pillow and tqdm module (Once python installed you can type on your console `pip install Pillow` and `pip install tqdm`)

Then you need to specify the directory on your console and launch the script with python `name_of_your_file.py`

Make your you put the correct input and output folder as well as the path to your font

Here is the script (# are comment that explain how it works)

I tried it with python 3.6 on macOS

```
# Modules Used
import os
from glob import glob

# Pillow module used to open and modify the images
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

# Tqdm module used to have a loading bar in your console (It will also calculate an average of time the program needs to run)
from tqdm import tqdm

# Path to your folder
path_to_folder = "inputs/"

# Path to the system font you're using 
# here the arial true type is in the script folder
path_to_font = "arial.ttf"
# Font size (in px) [if needed it can be in % of width or height of the document]
font_size = 128
font = ImageFont.truetype(path_to_font, font_size)

# Font color is in RGB 0-255 (here it's black) [red is (255, 0, 0)]
font_color = (0, 0, 0)

# Path to the Ouput folder 
# MAKE SURE THE FOLDER EXISTS ELSE IT WILL TROW AN ERROR
output_folder = "my_output_folder/"

# Find all the files in your folder 
# If you need also .png files you can write:
# list_of_files = glob(path_to_folder + '*.png') + glob(path_to_folder + '*.jpg')

list_of_files = glob(path_to_folder + '*.jpg')


# Loop through all your files 
for index, file in tqdm(enumerate(list_of_files)):

    # Open the file
    img = Image.open(file)
    # get the size of the image
    W, H = img.size

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Text Position: in the down right corner
    text_position = (W - font_size, H - font_size)

    # if you want it to alternate like in an average pagination from right to left corner you can 
    #text_position = (W - font_size, H - font_size) if (index % 2) else (0, H - font_size)

    # Write the text on your image (index start at 0 so you need to add one)
    draw.text(text_position,f"{index + 1}", font_color,font=font)
    # Get the file name 
    head, tail = os.path.split(file)
    # write the new image file in the correct folder with the name of the img
    img.save(os.path.join(output_folder, tail))
```